# representing a perfect square as a sum of perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, logic, induction

**Problem Statement**:

*Question-1:*

For every natural number $n \geq 1$ , show that there exists $(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{N}^*$  s.t :

$a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2$ is a perfect square.

*Question-2:*

Show that there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t :

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : a_1^2+a_2^2+..+a_n^2$ is a perfect square .

**My approach:**

I tried Using principle of mathematical induction to solve the first Question :

for $n=1$ , it suffices to choose $a_1=m$ with $m\in \mathbb{N}$

for $n=2$ , any pyhtagorean triple will work , we can choose for instance $a_1=3$ and $a_2=4$ , it will yield $a_1^2+a_2^2=5^2$

Let $n \geq 2$ such that  :$ \exists (a_1,...a_n) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $S_n=a_1^2+...+a_n^2$  is a perfect square (i.e  $ S_n=k^2 $ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$)

To prove the statement is true for $n+1$ it suffices to show that :

$$\exists (a,z)\in \mathbb{N}^2 : a^2+k^2=z^2$$
and then set $a_{n+1}=a$

I get stuck here in fact i don't think a solution exists for all k.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint for Q1: Start with $25S_n=(5a_1)^2+\ldots+(5a_n)^2$ and try to make that into a sum of $n+1$ squares.

Comment: Hint:  Pythagorean triples are a good idea.  Start with $3^2+4^2=5^2$.  Now $5=3^2-2^2$ so we have the primitive triple $(5, 12, 13)$ Similarly $13=7^2-6^2$ so we have the Pythagorean triple $(13, 84,85)$.  Now keep going.

Comment: $25Sn =(5a_1)^2+ \dots +(5a_{n-1})^2+(3a_n)^2+(4a_n)^2 $ So overall n+1 squares and $25Sn$ is the product of two squares so it's a square Got it ! Thank you

Comment: @lulu I was able to write the explicit formule for the sequence $(a_n)$ in terms of a recursive relation Thanks for the hint !

Comment: Glad to have helped.  If you like, you can post your solution below....that way, people here can check it and the site can close the question.  Also, note that the sequence the algorithm I sketched  produces is [A127690](https://oeis.org/A127690) and that, somewhat interestingly, it's not minimal, see [A018930](https://oeis.org/A018930)

Comment: Indeed it corresponds to the one i that i found at the end of my calculations ! Thanks ! I'll try to write an answer tomorrow since it's getting really late here back home